# If the spectral radius of an operator $T$ is $>1$, show that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty$ diverges.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T: X \rightarrow X$ a bounded operator and $r_\sigma (T) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|T^n\|^{1/n}$ the spectral radius of $T$. Show that if $r_\sigma (T) > 1$ then the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty T^j$ does not converge.

Here we are talking about convergence in the operator norm. I think this could work out by showing that the partial sums are not Cauchy, that is, $\|\sum_{j=n}^m T^j\| \not\rightarrow 0$ as $n,m$ get bigger. I just don't know how to do this just with this information about the spectral radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the Banach algebra of operators on $X$ generated by $T$ and $I$.  Since the spectral radius of $T$ is bigger than 1, there exists some $x$ in the spectrum of $T$ with $|x|>1$.  So there is some complex homomorphism $\phi$ of $B$ sending $T$ to $x$.  If your series converges, then
$$\sum_n\phi(T)^n = \sum_n x^n$$ would also converge, but this is impossible.